# Error suddenly thrown VS30063: You are not authorized to access

Tags: c#, azure-devops

When i try to access my repo in VSTS in my app i'm suddently getting the error:
VS30063: You are not authorized to access https://XXXXX.visualstudio.com

The funny thing is the app that has the below code was working without any issues.

Here is the code that i have:

```
var cred = new VssClientCredentials();

cred.Storage = new VssClientCredentialStorage(storageKind: "VssApp2", 
storageNamespace: "VisualStudio");                                      

var connection = new VssConnection(new Uri(vstsUrl), cred);

var projectHttpClient = connection.GetClient<ProjectHttpClient>();

var project = projectHttpClient.GetProjects().Result.FirstOrDefault();
```

I tried closing Visual Studio, deleted history, deleting the VSAppkey from the registry and rebooted my computer. That did not work.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you or someone else recently changed the permissions / security of https://xxxxx.visualstudio.com/ ?

Comment: VS2015 or VS2017?

Comment: VS2017. If i use a PAT then it works so i'm not sure why VssClientCredentials is causing an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try do the following things:

- Sign out of web portal for VSTS (Azure-DevOps)
- Clear browser cache
- Check whether you have access to VSTS through Visual Studio in the web browser window
- Sign out of the account
- Clear browser cache
- Clear cache from:

  `C:\Users\[your username]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\5.0\Cache`

Comment: Unfortunately after following the steps you advised it still hasn't resolved the issue. However if I use PAT the exception is not thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following bit of code please. Let me know if that works

```
 Uri _uri = new Uri("https://dev.azure.com/MyAccount/");

var creds = new VssClientCredentials(new WindowsCredential(false),
                                     new VssFederatedCredential(false),
                                     CredentialPromptType.PromptIfNeeded);

VssConnection vssConnection = new VssConnection(_uri, creds);
await vssConnection.ConnectAsync();
```